# How can I locate this element using Xpath?

Tags: selenium, xpath

How to locate the element below in Selenium?

```
<input id="mainForm:field_LayFact450505264_16032015_145612--Order-ServiceClass_R" class="iceSelInpTxtTxt fieldTxt" type="text" value="" style="width: 150px;" onmousedown="this.focus();" onfocus="setFocus(this.id);svOnFocus(formOf(this), this, event, false);" onblur="setFocus('');svOnBlur(formOf(this), this, event);" name="mainForm:field_LayFact450505264_16032015_145612--Order-ServiceClass_R" autocomplete="off">
```

I tried with ends-with, it did not work.

Comment: which element .. where is your data, HTML code and xpath you have tried?

Comment: <input id="mainForm:field_LayFact450505264_16032015_145612--Order-ServiceClass_R" class="iceSelInpTxtTxt fieldTxt" type="text" value="" style="width: 150px;" onmousedown="this.focus();" onfocus="setFocus(this.id);svOnFocus(formOf(this), this, event, false);" onblur="setFocus('');svOnBlur(formOf(this), this, event);" name="mainForm:field_LayFact450505264_16032015_145612--Order-ServiceClass_R" autocomplete="off">

Comment: if the ID is not unique every-time you can try class name.You can search element via class name or if you want to use xpath try this //input[@class="iceSelInpTxtTxt fieldTxt"]

Comment: you are using selenium or selenium webDriver?

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement Element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Try any Below xpaths"))
```

If your input id is unique then use below xpath

```
//input[@id='mainForm:field_LayFact450505264_16032015_145612--Order-ServiceClass_R']
```

OR

```
//input[@name='mainForm:field_LayFact450505264_16032015_145612--Order-ServiceClass_R']
```

OR if the combination of both of id and name make them unique then use below xpath

```
//input[@name='mainForm:field_LayFact450505264_16032015_145612--Order-ServiceClass_R' and @id='mainForm:field_LayFact450505264_16032015_145612--Order-ServiceClass_R']
```

OR

```
//input[@class='iceSelInpTxtTxt fieldTxt']
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below

```
WebElement inputClass = driver.findElement(By.className("iceSelInpTxtTxt fieldTxt"));
```